# T-SQL for loop through column names and insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, insert, data-warehouse

I'm working on data warehouse project, and i'm stuck on moment, where i need to loop through column names in dimension table and select value coresponding to specific column name in my base data table (the one with actual data, that i want to insert into fact table). Here's my table structure:

Data Table

```
closing_course | max_course | min_course
234            | 241        | 187
254            | 277        | 198
```

Dimension Table

```
course_id | course_type
1         | closing_course
2         | max_course
3         | min_course
```

In short i want to build a procedure that FOR EVERY COURSE TYPE it will get the VALUE of each course and insert course_id and coresponding value inside FACT TABLE (among other dimension data but i think i can handle that).

Comment: I don't understand your question. You've already put the course values into the fact table (I think) as measures, so why do you even need the dimension here? Are you trying to construct a query dynamically in a reporting tool? It would be helpful to see some DDL to show explicitly what the fact and dimension tables look like, and whatever query code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are looking for, maybe you could show an example what do you want to achieve. Here a some possible solution:

```
INSERT INTO FactTable (courseId,value)
SELECT 1, closing_course FROM DataTable
UNION
SELECT 2, max_course FROM DataTable
UNION
SELECT 3, min_course FROM DataTable
```